# Draw more images in canvas over each other

Tags: canvas, drawimage

I am trying to plot more images where every new image cover the oldest. Iam using Google chrome, but the canvas code draws images in random order.

**The function for drawing image is:**

```
function paint_img(obrazek,x,y,sirka,vyska){

  var obrazekk = new Image();

  obrazekk.src = obrazek;

  obrazekk.onload = function(value) { 

  aaac.drawImage(obrazekk,x ,y ,sirka ,vyska);

  };

   //aaac.moveToTop();

   //aaac.stroke();

   //aaac.restore();

}
```

**But when i am trying to draw more images their order is random. They are not drawen in order img1, img2, img3 and than img4 by (for example) this code:**

```
for (i=1;i<=10;i++){

 paint_img("img"+i+".png",1,1,100,100)

}
```

**I can not post example where the pictures are drawen in random order.**

Answer (score 1):

The random order is because the images finish loading in more or less random order.

You can solve this by a slightly different approach -

First create a loop that stores your image elements in an array:

```
var images = [],               /// image element array
    count = 10,                /// number of images to load
    loaded = count,            /// counter (decremented later)
    i = 1;

for (;i <= count;i++){
     var img = new Image();    /// create new image element
     img.onload = done;        /// set load handler
     img.src = "img"+ i +".png"; /// set source
     images.push(img);         /// push to array
}
```

This will guarantee the order of the images in our next step. As you can see the load handler is shared so we need to count number of images loaded:

```
function done() {
    loaded--;                  /// decrement loaded counter
    if (loaded === 0)          /// when done, draw images
        drawImages();
}
```

Now when the images has loaded we can draw them and they will be drawn in the order you would expect:

```
function drawImages() {
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        aaac.drawImage(images[i], 1, 1, 100, 100);
    }

    /// continue your script from here...
}
```

The example here does not have an error handler which you of course should add at least in the final code.

Hope this helps!